# grails-events-push plugin problems with Grails 2.3.3

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have the following config in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
plugins {
    ...
    compile ':events-push:1.0.M7'
}
```

It is working fine updating the project with that change. However when I start the application I will get:

```
 Running Grails application
| Error 2014-01-14 23:59:33,800 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'grailsEventsPublisher': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'boolean' for property 'catchFlushExceptions'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [boolean] for property 'catchFlushExceptions': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject]
Message: Error creating bean with name 'grailsEventsPublisher': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'boolean' for property 'catchFlushExceptions'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [boolean] for property 'catchFlushExceptions': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject]
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'boolean' for property 'catchFlushExceptions'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [boolean] for property 'catchFlushExceptions': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject]
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [boolean] for property 'catchFlushExceptions': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject]
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51065', transport: 'socket'
```

Is this some problems related to running this version of the plugin with Grails 2.3.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the platform-core plugin that the events plugin depends on. When a value isn't set in `Config.groovy` (and in general when using `ConfigSlurper` and `ConfigObject`) the value of a property will be a new empty `ConfigObject` the first time it's accessed. This causes weird errors if not properly handled, for example since it's a `Map` and it's empty, the `toString()` value is `[:]`. Empty maps are Groovy-false, so using `if` tests will work in general, but here it's assuming that a boolean value is set.

Based on the settings in the `doWithConfigOptions` block it appears that the default value of `catchFlushExceptions` is `true`, so adding this to your app's `Config.groovy` will get past this problem:

```
plugin.platformCore.events.catchFlushExceptions = true
```

Comment: Thanks!!, huge headache solved for a similar problem in Spring Security